# Assertion fails after using memcpy()

Tags: c, assert

I have the following code, where the assertion fails. Can anyone explain me why?

```
double *E = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * voxelSpaceSize);
double *E_new = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * voxelSpaceSize);

// ...some manipulations inside E and E_new, the memory locations do not change though
...

memcpy(E, E_new, sizeof(double) * voxelSpaceSize);        

for (int i=0; i<voxelSpaceSize; i++) {
  assert(E[i] == E_new[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's the _real_ code where `...` is?

Comment: If the arrays pointed by E and E_new overlap, memcpy( ) soils the bed. You might want to try memmove( ) instead.

Comment: I've added the allocation line.
... denotes various loops and assignments using E[..] = ..., E_new[...] = .... 
Shouldn't be relevant to the question, should it?

Comment: Could you print that is in both arrays (or a few samples if too large), what value `voxelSpaceSize` has before and after, etc? If voxelSpaceSize became larger, this may lead to an overlap.

Comment: What is the size of voxelSpaceSize? Could there be an overflow in  `sizeof(double) * voxelSpaceSize`

Comment: "Shouldn't be relevant to the question, should it?" No, shouldn't be relevant but almost certainly is.  I don't see any faults in the code you've posted so I think the fault must be in code you haven't posted.

Comment: Try `assert( fabs(E[i]-E_new[i])< 0.00000001 )`. maybe problem is the precision of `double` comparison.

Comment: If you can't post the full unadulterated real code, then create a minimal test case that still displays the issue and post that here instead. If you're lucky, in the process of doing that you'll find the problem yourself anyway.

Comment: On what architecture? Compiler? OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the special floating-point value `NaN` is not equal to itself: `NaN == NaN` returns false. So now I'm betting the value at the unequal  index is `NaN`. You may want to print out the value  at the index where the value's not equal to itself, rather than using `assert`.

Comment: Yep, that was it, thanks! For some reason I was assuming that memcpy was wrong.

Comment: w00t! Second time's the charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy from `E` to `E_new`, your arguments to `memcpy` are in the wrong order -- the second argument is the source pointer, the first is the destination.

Comment: So he's copying into E from E_new. How does that change his question?

Comment: Exactly -- two things should be still equal.